# How old is Doc Brown at the end of Back to the Future 3?

Tags: back-to-the-future-iii

How old is Doctor Emmett Brown at the end of the Back to the Future trilogy?

Comment: It depends; https://backtothefuture.fandom.com/wiki/Emmett_Brown

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Based on the movies alone, we don't know how old Doc was at the end of the third film, since none of them tell us how old he was at any point, or when he was born.

According to the official novelisation of the first film though, he was sixty-five years of age when that film began on the morning of October 25th 1985.

> **At sixty-five, he was one of the nation's most talented and most unheralded inventors.** In fact, no one except Marty McFly even knew of his accomplishments, but that didn't matter. Soon all that would change. His lifetime of struggle, of being the recipient of ridicule, would suddenly turn golden.
>
> [...]
>
> The fact that Doc Brown's work yielded nothing should have discouraged him but did not. Through the '50s, '60s, '70s, and into the '80s, he continued to experiment, earning perennial scorn as the crazy scientist of Hill Valley.
>
> **Now, on October 25, 1985, he was ready for fulfillment.**
>
> <sub>[*Back to the Future* novelisation by George Gipe](https://backtothefuture.fandom.com/wiki/Back_to_the_Future_novelization)</sub>

The screenplay for the first film more or less agrees, stating that he was about 65 years old.

> **The driver is DR. EMMETT BROWN, about 65.** He looks like an old hippie, with shoulder length white hair, Hawaiian shirt, faded jeans, an Indian turquoise around his neck and lively -- almost wild -- eyes. He's full of energy, full of life, talks fast, and is immediately likable for his eccentricities.
>
> <sub>[*Back to the Future* screenplay by Robert Zemeckis and Bob Gale](http://www.dailyscript.com/scripts/bttf4th.pdf)</sub>

We also know that he ages several years during the events of the third film, since he has two sons, both of whom are clearly several years old when he returns to 1985 near the end of the film. Neither of those boys were born yet, or likely even conceived, when Marty last saw him in 1885.

We can confirm that Doc initially arrived in 1885 on January 1st, since that's the date which appeared as the destination time on the display of the time machine, shortly before he inadvertently made that trip in the second film.

[image]

And according to *[Back to the Future #25: Time Served Part 4](https://backtothefuture.fandom.com/wiki/Back_to_the_Future_25:_Time_Served_Part_4)*, he and his family didn't finally leave the 1800s until September 9th 1893, which means he spent over eight-and-a-half years in that time period, before returning to 1985 at the end of the third film. This story was co-written by Bob Gale, who also co-wrote the original films with Robert Zemeckis.

[image]

So if we add all that together, **Doc has to be at least 73 years old, or possibly 74, by the end of the third film.**

Doc also spent an unknown period of time in 2015 (possibly weeks or months) during the events of the first film, but while we can't be sure quite how long he was there, it probably wasn't long enough to make him any older than 74 by the end of the third film, and he could still potentially have been 73.

Comment: Also the time at the rejuvenation clinic in 2015 as he mentioned to Marty in the second film, adding several years to his life.